# Unknown Slot types

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I have just started looking into making a basic Alexa skill.

I want to create a skill that repeats what a user says. For example "Alexa, repeat 'hello'".

What slot type would I use for hello as I am unaware of what the user will say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Catch-all" for Alexa Skills Kit input not in defined intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694131/catch-all-for-alexa-skills-kit-input-not-in-defined-intent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Josep Valls answer is false:

1. The Amazon.LITERAL Slot-Type can still be used. Amazon planned on removing it, but due to developer feedback reverted that decision. [Here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference#literal) is the documentation.
2. Even without the literal type you can catch everything an user says. This includes values that are not pre-defined. Quoting [this](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3IHSFQSUF3RQP/why-a-custom-slot-is-the-literal-solution):

> "When you create a custom slot type, a key concept to understand is
>   that this is training data for Alexa’s NLP (natural language
>   processing). The values you provide are NOT a strict enum or array
>   that limit what the user can say. This has two implications 1) words
>   and phrases not in your slot values will be passed to you, 2) your
>   code needs to perform any validation you require if what’s said is
>   unknown."

Comment: The LITERAL slot type only exists in US English, however, as your say, it definitely is possible to capture input speech using a custom slot type, which is exactly what I'm doing for a skill I'm developing.

Comment: Removed my answer. Last time I checked the documentation the note about the LITERAL slot types being available again was not there.